# Use class method not instance method with the same name

Tags: python, metaclass

I have the following snippet:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        pass

class Klass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def get(self, arg):
        pass
```

Now, if I do:

```
kls = Klass()
kls.get('arg')
```

everything works as expected (the instance method `get` is called).

But if I do:

```
Klass.get('arg')
```

again the instance method is found and an exception is given, since it is treated as an unbound method.

How can I make a call to `Klass.get('arg')` go through the `__getattr__` defined in the metaclass? I need this because I want to proxy all methods called on a class to another object (this would be done in `__getattr__`).

Comment: Have you thought about overriding `__getattribute__` and doing some checking in that logic?

Comment: Which `__getattribute__`?

Comment: `Met.__getattribute__`. Since `__getattribute__` is called *before* dict lookup (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: It could be, but I don't want to add extra checks on **all** method calls as it introduces quite an overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to look up the method on the type and pass in the first (`self`) argument manually:

```
type(Klass).get(Klass, 'arg')
```

This problem is the very reason that [special method names are looked up using this path](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup); custom classes would not be hashable or representable themselves if Python didn't do this.

You *could* make use of that fact; rather than use a `get()` method, use `__getitem__`, overloading `[..]` indexing syntax, and have Python do the `type(ob).methodname(ob, *args)` dance for you:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        pass

class Klass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        pass
```

and then `Klass()['arg']` and `Klass['arg']` work as expected.

However, if you have to have `Klass.get()` behave differently (and the lookup for this to be intercepted by `Meta.__getattribute__`) you have to explicitly handle this in your `Klass.get` method; it'll be called with one argument less if called on the class, you could make use of that and return a call on the class:

```
_sentinel = object()

class Klass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def get(self, arg=_sentinel):
        if arg=_sentinel:
            if isinstance(self, Klass):
                raise TypeError("get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'")
            return type(Klass).get(Klass, self)
        # handle the instance case ...
```

You could also handle this in a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) that mimics method objects:

```
class class_and_instance_method(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        if instance is None:
            # return the metaclass method, bound to the class
            type_ = type(cls)
            return getattr(type_, self.func.__name__).__get__(cls, type_)
        return self.func.__get__(instance, cls)
```

and use this as a decorator:

```
class Klass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    @class_and_instance_method
    def get(self, arg):
        pass
```

and it'll redirect look-ups to the metaclass if there is no instance to bind to:

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         print 'Meta.{} look-up'.format(name)
...         return lambda arg: arg
... 
>>> class Klass(object):
...     __metaclass__ = Meta
...     @class_and_instance_method
...     def get(self, arg):
...         print 'Klass().get() called'
...         return 'You requested {}'.format(arg)
... 
>>> Klass().get('foo')
Klass().get() called
'You requested foo'
>>> Klass.get('foo')
Meta.get look-up
'foo'
```

Applying the decorator can be done in the metaclass:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, body):
        for name, value in body.iteritems():
            if name in proxied_methods and callable(value):
                body[name] = class_and_instance_method(value)
        return super(Meta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, body)
```

and you can then add methods to classes using this metaclass without having to worry about delegation:

```
>>> proxied_methods = ('get',)
>>> class Meta(type):
...     def __new__(mcls, name, bases, body):
...         for name, value in body.iteritems():
...             if name in proxied_methods and callable(value):
...                 body[name] = class_and_instance_method(value)
...         return super(Meta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, body)
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         print 'Meta.{} look-up'.format(name)
...         return lambda arg: arg
... 
>>> class Klass(object):
...     __metaclass__ = Meta
...     def get(self, arg):
...         print 'Klass().get() called'
...         return 'You requested {}'.format(arg)
... 
>>> Klass.get('foo')
Meta.get look-up
'foo'
>>> Klass().get('foo')
Klass().get() called
'You requested foo'
```

Comment: The `get` method was just a name, it doesn't do anything near `__getitem__`. But thank you for pointing that solution too. So isn't there any other solution to this but that "ugly" call? I am trying to build an interface for underlying operations and I was looking for something prettier...P.S.: The link you've posted doesn't find the "#" part.

Comment: I've edited my question, added my actual concern to it (sorry for not being specific from the beginning, wanted to make the example as simple as I could).

Comment: @AndreiHorak: link fixed (it was originally a Python 3 link and I manually adjusted it for 2, but forgot the section title had changed).

Comment: @AndreiHorak: your changed question is now very different but the solution should be clear; `type(self)[arg]` or `Klass[arg]` in the `Klass.get()` method will translate to `Meta.__getitem__`.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: in other words, you renamed the method and the problem *went away*.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: as such, I'm inclined to revert your edit; your new version is not really a problem, you reduced the clarity of the question.

Comment: I don't want to reach the metaclass `__getattr__` from `Klass.get`. I want the call to `Klass().get()` to reach `Klass.get` and the call to `Klass.get()` to reach `Meta.__getattr__('get')`.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: that is just.. weird. Why would you want to do *that*? Unless you put methods directly on the instances you cannot reliably distinguish between the two uses of `Klass.get` in that case. You'd have to use a custom descriptor object to detect the difference.

Comment: Well, I need to proxy all class method calls to a single object. So I "grab" these calls with a `__getattr__` that acts on `Klass` and dispatch from there to the right proxied object. Otherwise, I would have had to define all the proxy methods as class methods on `Klass` or methods on `Meta`. Is there a better way than the one I figured out?

Comment: @AndreiHorak: The moment you define your own `.get()` you are basically short-circuiting the proxy lookup. In that case the `.get()` method itself will have to delegate back to the metaclass. I've added an option to do so.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Thought there was a way to cleanly dispatch to the metaclass when calling the method on the class. Thank you for your help and for bearing with me!

Comment: @AndreiHorak: I've updated the answer to include a descriptor approach. You could even do the decoration in the metaclass.